# Task Completion Status: x/y versus "In Progress" "To Do" etc?

Tags: navigation, user-expectation, task-completion

We are creating an UI element to show task completion and are leaning more towards showing a number of tasks completed as compared to the words.
e.g.

- "0/3" v/s  "To Do"
- "1/3" v/s "In Progress"
- "✔" v/s "Completed"

Our justifications for these design choices are:

- Translation overhead for the words is extra effort for the designers.
- The words take up more space.
- The gamification aspect of the number/number would increase user engagement
- The words do not give an actual estimate of how much work is left to do

I would like the validation and/or rebuttal to these justifications.

Thanks!

Comment: Only use numbers if the individual steps are of very similar length.

Answer (score 1):

**context, context, context**

Like everything UX, you need context. **In a vacuum, the words are better**, because they explain there's a task, and a status of this task. Numbers indicate that something is going on. At best.

Now, **if you have proper labeling, all your points are valid**. With just a tiny little change in your context, you can (and should) use the complete opposite approach.

However, your variables are almost labels. So, if the task is implicit within a broader task or flow, you could simply get rid of the labels and use variables as labels (hence, words). Since `label+numberVariables` will be longer than just `label`, you can make a case for that, exception made of your last item.

In short: barring **labeling, space considerations and TESTING**, I'd say **your approach is sound and quite probably correct**

Comment: In general I agree with this answer, except for this: "Numbers indicate that something is going on. At best."   Numbers indicate roughly *how much* progress has been made: I know which step I'm on, and I know how many steps there are going to be. "In Progress" only communicates "I'm not done yet."   For that one example, even out of context, the numbers are a clear improvement over the indeterminate "in progress".   (Perhaps it should be "step 1/3" instead of just "1/3", but that does come down to context.)

Comment: @DanielBeck, you're correct, but I'm talking about a scenario where you have no labels, only numbers. This would mean anything at all, while an implicit task with words might be a lot more informative

Comment: Even without the label I'd say "1/3" communicates more than "in progress" -- but of course I'm assuming that those numbers would be in a context that implies they're indicators for a stepped process.  Which brings us tidily back to your original point :)

Comment: @g0rd 99% certain? 99% finished? 99% of the userbase? 99% of the events? I think you mean certain, but without labeling I can not be 100%. (sure)